# CSS columns not displaying as expected in Opera (look okay in Firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, opera

I'm trying to create a layout with automatic CSS columns. They look fine in Firefox but behave very strangely in Opera (both latest versions, Mac).

In Opera when there is sufficient content, the text all appears vertically centred in the columns, whereas I want it to be top-aligned (and would expect it to be by default).

Also if there is a lot of content without a break, it reverts to a single column and seems to 'break out' of the flow.

I have tried vertical-align and I have been fiddling about with flex – but this seems to break the columns completely.

```
.two-col .textwidget {
    -webkit-column-gap: 50px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 50px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 50px;
    -webkit-column-count:2;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
    column-count:2;
}
```

As I said in Firefox it appears how I would expect and how I would like. In Opera – no.

Comment: I forgot to link an example page: https://dev.tinkertailordesign.com/lancea2/alternative-funds-advisory/secondary-markets/

Comment: UPDATE: It seems to not be vertical alignment, but rather a wrapping issue. Space is left for the content to wrap from the first to second column, but the content DOESN'T wrap